# Constructors - regarding performance?

Tags: c++, performance, oop, class, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optimization due to constructor initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386848/optimization-due-to-constructor-initializer-list)

OK, so here's my dilemma : Let's say we've got a class, along with several constructors, which are going to be called numerous times (some hundreds of millions of times per second; so **speed is crucial**).

Which way is preferable? (Is there any difference at all?)

**Way A :**

```
// Prototype
class MyClass
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        MyClass (int x, int y, int z) : X(x), Y(y), Z(z) {}

        // Variables
        int X,Y,Z;
};
```

**Way B :**

```
// Prototype
class MyClass
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        MyClass (int x, int y, int z);

        // Variables
        int X,Y,Z;
};

// Implementation
MyClass::MyClass(int x,int y,int z)
{
     this->X=x;
     this->Y=y;
     this->Z=z;
}
```

Comment: Why guess/ask rather than just measure?

Comment: @NPE I'm asking first to avoid rewriting some one hundred lines, simply because of a notion of mine that might be wrong after all (I mean from a theoretical point of view)...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: You could construct a synthetic benchmark, and get a very accurate answer that's relevant to your environment.

Comment: The best optimisation would probably be to *not* construct hundreds of millions of things per second.

Comment: @JasonD Unfortunately, this is unavoidable, because of the very nature of the project I'm working on...

Comment: There appears to be 2 parts to this question - [inlining a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303/in-c-can-constructor-and-destructor-be-inline-functions) and [using an initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386848/optimization-due-to-constructor-initializer-list) (both pointing to the first being faster).

Comment: I can see no circumstance where the second variant would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use profile tool to measure it by yourself. With build-in types maybe there is no difference (*regarding construction speed*) but for class types, using a member initializer list is always preferable way.

Answer (score 0):

In the wise words of one Donald Knuth:

> [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Write the code in whatever style is the most readable and maintainable; my personal preference is to have the implementation outside the header separately.  If it's small enough to inline, the compiler will inline it; if the compiler decides that it's big enough not to inline (to reduce code size and save instruction cache space, or whatever), then the compiler won't inline it.

Then benchmark, and optimize based on *real empirical data*.