# Understanding of "inline" in C++ class constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, inline, declaration

I read a source code of class **address_v4** in boost library and there are several constructors declared with BOOST_ASIO_DECL (defined as inline)

```
/// Construct an address from raw bytes.
BOOST_ASIO_DECL explicit address_v4(const bytes_type& bytes);

/// Construct an address from a unsigned long in host byte order.
BOOST_ASIO_DECL explicit address_v4(unsigned long addr);
```

(from here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/asio/ip/address_v4.hpp)

```
# define BOOST_ASIO_DECL inline
```

(from here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp)

So, what the purpose of specifing "inline" for c++ constructor ? Is it the same meaning as for functions or it has a different meaning ?

Comment: The `inline` keyword has the same meaning everywhere in C++: It's a *suggestion* that the compiler is allowed to inline the function.

Comment: But for constructors, how can they be inlined ?

Comment: Short answer: yes, constructors and destructors can be inlined. They're just functions, after all.

Comment: When you construct an object, the constructor is called like any other member function, and can therefore be inlined just like any other function.

Comment: @Some programmer dude - it also has meaning related to ODR. It's use as a inlining hint is mostly ignored by modern compilers.

Comment: Constructors _are_ functions. Your question is missing a useful premise.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Why don't you want to use your dupehammer?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Because that other question wasn't really talking about the `inline` keyword. I know it doesn't make much difference to the code here, but it's a small difference and I wasn't confident the OP would understand why their question was a duplicate of that other and how the answers apply to him/her.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has exactly the same meaning (as *some programmer dude* noted the ctor is a function like any other) but given that any compiler (I can think of) will happily ignore your suggestion (to decide if inline is required or not using all his knowledge) then it has to have another use...

In fact it's there to define a function (or ctor) in your header file without the errors linker will raise because of the **one definition rule**.

Note that it opens another scenario when function has not a body: to define the function in multiple translation units. In this case each implementation must be the same (AFAIK, please correct me if I'm wrong) or it's UB.

In short: define a function in your header file and use it in multiple translation units: linker error. Mark it as inline and errors are gone (and it won't imply that function is really inlined).

Comment: You ought to explayin *why* the error is gone in the "function defined in header" case - that is, the meaning of `inline` in a ODR context (since that's the only *real* meaning the keyword has these days). Just saying "error is gone" isn't really enough of an explanation of *why*.

Comment: Is it right that this constructors (which have no body and have "inline") can be defined multible times in different files and linker proceed they correctly ?

Comment: Jesper, I agree that's why I mentioned odr the paragraph before!

Comment: Desi, yes you can do that but they MUST be equivalent (AFAIK it's undefined behavior if they differ)

Comment: You only need to add `inline` to your constructor definition if it's in the header but outside of the class definition. If the constructor is defined within the class definition itself, it's implicitly `inline`. This applies to all other member functions too.